# How to implement slug replacing id's in the URL

Tags: php, html, seo, slug

Presently I have a home page (index.php) which contains several links to an another page (story.php).In order to load different stories my hyper links are as follows

```
<a  href=”story.php?cat_id=0&n_id=2”>Best Mobile Phones of 2016</a>
```

As you can see that the URL is like : `story.php?cat_id=0&n_id=2`

I want to change the URL into a Slug like `Best-Mobile-Phones-of-2016`.The slugs are present as a field in a table.

Now my question is if I want to serve pages using slugs and not by id’s, then how should I go about?I mean to say that how should be my hyperlinks to different stories in the index.php.

I hope that you understand my question. Any help in this regard would be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SEO friendly links basically look like this: `story/Best-Mobile-Phones-of-2016` instead of `story.php?cat_id=0&n_id=2`.
Now when a user surfs that site, your .htaccess rewrites that url to e.g. `story.php?storyID=Best-Mobile-Phones-of-2016`. Your algorithm has to figure out which `cat_id` and `n_id` is associated with the `storyID`.
You can also append the `cat_id` and `n_id` to your `storyID`: `story.php?storyID=Best-Mobile-Phones-of-2016_0_2`. Then your algorithm can easily explode your `storyID`.

Hope that helped you.

Comment: Thanks @Luca.I think i got my answer.You have pointed me in the right direction.